# Display HTML in a Toast Popup Alert

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, toast

Is there any way to display HTML in a [Toast popup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_toast)?

I'd like to display a list of error messages, and not just a single string.

Comment: I am afraid that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast event can only have string message. Even if you try to pass html in message, it will be interpreted as text. You can use multiple toast events to show all the errors you have. Or, you can create your own toast component using the [lightningdesignsystem toast blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/#site-main-content). Add a ***slot*** inside the div with class **slds-notify__content**. You can add it wherever you want and control its rendering with the **if:true** directive.

```html
<div class="slds-notify__content">
  <slot></slot>
</div>
```